# How can I add existing items to a matrix in netsuite?

Tags: matrix, netsuite

I have several items in Netsuite that I want to group together but it seems like I can only add items to a matrix if they're new.

Comment: Can you add some more details please? What items do you have and how do you want them to group ? Is all are matrix items ?

Comment: I want to start by grouping pairs of dumbbells that range from 5-100 lb, so I'll put the pair weights (10 lb, 20 lb, ...) in the item property list. The problem is that I don't want to lose the purchase history on eBay, so I can't delete them in order to create new ones to be in a matrix variation.

Answer (score 1):

Once an item is created you cannot change its type and whether an item is a matrix item or not is part of its type. The only exception to this is where you can convert a non inventory item to inventory item.

However if the driver for this is how you display items on your website there are a number of ways to deal with this.

Both of these require some JavaScript skills

One is to create a site category and assign your "matrix" items to that. Then create an item list template for the category that makes it look like a buy page.

The other is to link the items under a new parent item ( can be natural parent field or custom item field) and use Ajax calls to a suitelet to load the child items and organize the page

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is only for 3rd party sites like Amazon and eBay. No way to do it?

Comment: Then just group them with either the natural parent or a custom item field and adjust how your feed groups them.

Comment: How can I group them like that?

Comment: I have no idea how your actual fees are set up.  Each feed has its own setup. Somewhere you have a feed that pulls items from your Netsuite account and posts them to Amazon and eBay. It will generally have a way to handle variants/matrix items.